# how to open a csv file in python having double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a huge file about 500k rows and 187 columns. After saving it into a csv file, I ran into a situation whereby my header is separated by semicolon (;) and the contents are also separated by the semicolons but wrapped in double quotes(""). Opening it with pandas does not look the way i want it to look. I tried using a csv model but the result is very disturbing. Available solutions on the net do not answer my task.

Below is the sample of my file from CouponSales&Refund.csv.

```
flt_no;aa_code;dep_port;arr_port;sch_dep_dt;sch_dep_dt_with_time;sch_arr_dt;sch_arr_dt_with_time
106;"SW";"OND";"ERS";"04-06-2020";"04/06/2020 15:50:00";"04-06-2020";"04/06/2020 16:45:00"
101;"SW";"ERS";"OND";"04-06-2020";"04/06/2020 08:20:00";"04-06-2020";"04/06/2020 09:15:00"
134;"SW";"MPA";"ERS";"21-06-2020";"21/06/2020 12:40:00";"21-06-2020";"21/06/2020 14:05:00"
```

This is what I have done so far but I am still not happy

```
import csv
with open('CouponSales&Refund.csv', 'rt') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)

    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)


df = pd.read_csv('CouponSales&Refund.csv', sep=";")
```

All I want is a tabular data. How Can I achieve that?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. How _does_ it look when you open it with `pandas`?

Comment: The head was read correctly. However all the contents are put in the first column:

106;"SW";"OND";"ERS";"04-06-2020";"04/06/2020 ...This is what is find under 'flt_no'
The rest of the columns are having NAN

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your csv hs newlines as in

```
lt_no;aa_code;dep_port;arr_port;sch_dep_dt;sch_dep_dt_with_time;sch_arr_dt;sch_arr_dt_with_time 
106;"SW";"OND";"ERS";"04-06-2020";"04/06/2020 15:50:00";"04-06-2020";"04/06/2020 16:45:00" 
101;"SW";"ERS";"OND";"04-06-2020";"04/06/2020 08:20:00";"04-06-2020";"04/06/2020 09:15:00" 
134;"SW";"MPA";"ERS";"21-06-2020";"21/06/2020 12:40:00";"21-06-2020";"21/06/2020 14:05:00"
```

I get

```
In [4]: pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', sep=';')                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[4]: 
   lt_no aa_code dep_port arr_port  sch_dep_dt sch_dep_dt_with_time  sch_arr_dt sch_arr_dt_with_time 
0    106      SW      OND      ERS  04-06-2020  04/06/2020 15:50:00  04-06-2020  04/06/2020 16:45:00 
1    101      SW      ERS      OND  04-06-2020  04/06/2020 08:20:00  04-06-2020  04/06/2020 09:15:00 
2    134      SW      MPA      ERS  21-06-2020  21/06/2020 12:40:00  21-06-2020   21/06/2020 14:05:00
```

`pd.read_csv` escapes double quotes by default.

Comment: opening it in Excel looks like there is a new line but i think there is no new line. Everything is dumped in column lt_no, the rest of the columns are having NAN